# How do I find out which module caused an error in Webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack

When I run `webpack`, I get `ERROR in Cannot find module 'lodash/lang/isFunction'`. However, multiple module depend on lodash. How do I make Webpack go into debug or verbose mode?

Adding `debug: true` in my Webpack config file didn't do anything.

Comment: I think, the error is already very explicit. Have you searched for the string `lodash/lang/isFunction` in your project?

Comment: It's in several of my node_modules, I ended up removing all the ones with `lodash/lang/isFunction` and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the [--display-error-details](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#display-error-details) flag? Setting this when executing a build gives you more verbose output on errors (e.g. when a module is missing it will show you all the places it looked to find it). As far as I can tell this is command line only; I haven't been able to find an equivalent when running webpack via node.

Comment: The equivalent in node is to check the `stats` which are passed as result to the callback.

Comment: @jhnns Thanks, very helpful!